# Translate this curl command to php curl

Tags: php, docker, curl

I am trying to write a php file to consume a micro service inside of a docker container that converts a html into a pdf.

I can do it with no problem in this way:

```
curl -vv -F --output 'file=@/home/user/Documents/contract.html' http://0.0.0.0:32768/ -o /home/user/contract.pdf
```

And now I'm trying to "translate" this command in a php file but is my first time with curl in php.

```
    //Initialise the cURL var
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Get the response from cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //Set the Url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://0.0.0.0:32768/');

    //Create a POST array with the file in it
    $postData = array(
        'testData' => '@/home/user/Documents/contract.html',
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    // Execute the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
```

I'm missing the `-o` option of the command, the path and name of the file I should get after converting the html file to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `CURLOPT_FILE`.

> CURLOPT_FILE  The file that the transfer should be written to. The default is STDOUT (the browser window).

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "curl%20-vv%20-F%20--output%20'file=@/home/user/Documents/contract.html'%20http://0.0.0.0:32768/%20-o%20/home/user/contract.pdf%0A%0A",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```